# ufw status | ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ufw

Делаю скрипт для вывода состояния работы служб , по принципу

```
ps -A | grep name_process | wc -l
```

Соответственно вывод - 0 или 1.

Для ufw нет процесса, поэтому пошел по пути:

```
service ufw status  | grep -qi "active" && echo ="1"
```

Однако при этом, не будет вывода 0 , если ufw не запущен.

пробовал что-то типа :

```
service ufw status  | grep -qi "active" && echo ="1" || grep -qi "inactive" && echo ="0"
```

или:

```
service ufw status  | grep -qi "active" && echo ="1" ||service ufw status | grep -qi "inactive" && echo ="0"
```

Однако вывод:

```
0
1
```

Прошу помочь с выводом 1, при запущенном фаерволе, и 0 при мертвом.

Answer (score 0):

Вот очень грубо по памяти и навскидку:

```
if [[ "$(LANG=en_US sudo ufw status)" =~ "inactive" ]]; then  
    echo 0
else
    echo 1
fi
```

> **LANG=en_US** лучше использовать, поскольку при запуске скрипта в системе с локалью отличной от en_US то вероятно что никакого "inactive" там не будет, а будет что-то типа "не активен"